# share a function to others scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, requirejs

I have a scripting file (Shared.js) which contains a function that I want to use from within other two js files, sampleA.js, sampleB.js.

**Shared.js:**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({       
        rotaterator: function (options) {
                      .....
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**sampleA.js:**

```
function A(block) {
   $('.SomeItemAA').rotaterator({ ... });
};
```

**sampleB.js:**

```
function B(block) {
   $('.SomeItemBB').rotaterator({ ... });
};
```

sampleA.js and sampleB.js are loaded in my asp.net mvc 4 view using script tag.

so how to do this using require.js? is it possible?

Comment: Well did you look at the requirejs docs? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just put them in the head of the page in the order you want them to load and execute.  As long as shared.js is loaded before the other 2 script files they will be able to use and global functions, such as the one you created above.

Comment: Initially I include Shared.js in the view page containing sampleA.js and sampleB.js, but it was not working. The view page which is using sampleA.js and sampleB.js is included in a master page and it seems to not work. Instead, if I include Shared.js in the master page it is working. I do not know why...

Comment: You *should* have shared.js in the master page, as that's the core script.  You'd have the other 2 optional files included in the head content in pages that inherit the master page, as and when you need them.

Comment: @Archer sorry, you are right. My problem was in the order they were being loaded. Now it works. Thanks very much.